# Astropy add checksum to existing fits file

Tags: python, astropy

I already have a fits file written (someone sent it to me) and I want to add a checksum and datasum to the header. The only examples I found with adding a checksum using [astropy.io.fits](http://astropy.readthedocs.org/en/stable/io/fits/index.html) involve building a new fits [HDU and verifying it](http://astropy.readthedocs.org/en/stable/io/fits/usage/verification.html) on adding each section to the HDU. Which I could do, but that seems a like it would have a lot more overhead then is needed.

Is there a way to add a checksum and datasum to an existing HDU?

Comment: Check the docs for HDUList.writeto.

Comment: @Iguananaut - It seems that this requires rewriting the the HDU. I was wondering if there is a way to do it without rewriting the file. It says "Create a new FITS file using the supplied data/header" http://astropy.readthedocs.org/en/stable/io/fits/api/files.html#astropy.io.fits.writeto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ImageHDU` objects have a method called [`add_checksum()`](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/api/images.html#astropy.io.fits.ImageHDU.add_checksum). That should do exactly what you want.

---

So you could open a FITS file in update mode and then call this and close the file again.

```
from astropy.io import fits

with fits.open(filename, mode='update') as hdus:
    hdus[0].add_checksum() # Fill in the arguments like you need them
```

The `with` is preferred because it automatically `close`s the file when the `with` context is exited (even if an exception happens) but you could also open and close it without the `with`:

```
from astropy.io import fits

hdul = fits.open(filename, mode='update')
hdul[0].add_checksum()
hdul.close()
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that requires rewriting the HDU. I was wondering if there is a way to do it without rewriting the HDU.

Comment: Do you mean: Writing checksum and datasum without writing it to the disk?

Comment: Without re-writing all of the data to disk. I want to calculate the values and update the header keywords.

Comment: I've edited the answer - This only writes changes to the disk. But I'm not quite sure if there might be problems with scaled data.

Comment: Thank you. I did not have any issues with the scaling of my data, it seems to have been untouched.